# How to automatically change TODO priority in Org-mode based on number of days to a deadline?

Tags: org-mode

Is there a way to automatically specify a TODO items' priority based on the number of days to a given deadline?

For example, if the deadline for the TODO is `<2021-01-22 Fri>`, I would like the priority set automatically to `[#C]`, then on Fri 8th Jan 2021 the priority would be automatically set to `[#B]`, and finally on Fri 15th Jan 2021 the priority is set to `[#A]`.

Comment: You can surely write a function to to do that: go over all agenda files, find items with the required properties and change the priority. That's the "easy" part, I think. The main difficulty afterwards will be how/when to call the function. The most likely place is probably from `org-agenda-mode-hook`, so that you get the new priorities in the agenda, but that has the disadvantage of slowing down agenda genaration. Perhaps a timer at midnight can be used to call the function, but that assumes that emacs is always running, If not, perhaps a cron job, assuming the machine is always up.

Comment: @NickD thanks for your suggestions, I'll have a look into ```org-agenda-mode-hook```. I'm not keen to setup a timer/cron job since my org files are hosted externally (Dropbox) and I access them on multiple machines that are not always up.

Comment: I'm not sure of what is the point of this approach, as the info you're looking for is already in the deadline, I'd rather go with custom agenda sections, will tweak `org-agenda-sorting-strategy`, or even use different TODO keywords for that, leaving priorities for what they are, like noting priorities on multiple taks with same deadline.

Comment: That is a very good point: if the OP is trying to change the order of appearance in the agenda, there are more direct methods of doing that than changing the priority of items (which in most cases should probably not change, or at least only change in response to changes of plan, not in the "normal" course of events).

Comment: Many thanks to authors of the comments above, they helped me realize that automatically adjusting org tags in the .org file was not the best approach to what I wanted (automatic ordering of todos in agenda view based on deadline). A better approach is to use a tool like [org-super-agenda](https://github.com/alphapapa/org-super-agenda).

Comment: This is a link-only answer, so it risks being deleted. Please at least summarize the info at the link, to explain how it answers the question.